# Old Testament verses about faith in the promised Messiah

Tags: faith

I am looking for Old Testament verses about faith in the promised Messiah.  It would help to have Old Testament scripture to show continuity with New Testament scripture concerning the promise of the Messiah.

Comment: There are multiple quotes available online, for example at [Grace Theological Seminary](https://seminary.grace.edu/old-testament-prophecies-about-the-coming-of-the-messiah/) and at [Wikipedia - Old Testament Messianic Prophecies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Testament_messianic_prophecies_quoted_in_the_New_Testament).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  Please take our Tour to understand what we look for in well researched questions and answers: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

The word "Messiah" for a specific future individual appears only in very few passages of the OT.

Psalm 2.2 - "his Anointed" can equally be translated "his Messiah".  The whole of Psalm 2 then becomes plainly a Psalm indicating this Messiah will also be the Son of God (7, 12), who will bring salvation to the nations (v8).

Isaiah 45:1 "his anointed", a Messiah,refers here to the Persian King Cyrus, who will "save" the Jews from captivity in Babylonia, and allow them to return to Judaea and rebuild the temple in Jerusalem. Isaiah prophesied the decree of Cyrus about 150 years beforehand.

Daniel 9:25 and 26 refer to the coming Messiah, and are fulfilled in Jesus Christ. This "Messiah shall be cut off but not for himself".. he will not die for his own sins but for the sins of others. (The accuracy of the timing of the 70 weeks (v24) is astonishing.. see other questions in stack exchange Christianity and Hermeneutics.)

Other passages talk of anointed ones, but they refer to men being anointed to be king or anointed to be a priest.  The anointing in each case symbolises they are God's choice, the one chosen for that position/task.

The first promise of a Saviour is in Genesis 3:15. See also Psalm 22:16, Isaiah 53, isaiah 28:16, 49:6; job 19:25-27; Psalm 118:22-23.

Answer (score 1):

Job, Abraham and Moses all had faith in God’s promise of a future Messiah.  Although their understanding of who this Messiah would be was not known to them, they acted in faith, trusting God’s promises.

> I know that my Redeemer lives, and that in the end he will stand upon the earth (Job 19:25).

Moses abandoned the power, privilege and wealth of Pharaoh’s house to stand alongside God’s chosen people through whom the Messiah would be born:

> He regarded disgrace for the sake of Christ [the Greek name for the Hebrew name Messiah] as of greater value than the treasures of Egypt, because he was looking ahead to his reward (Hebrews 11:26).

This Messiah was revealed to the prophet Isaiah 700 years in advance of the birth of Jesus, the Christ:

> Therefore the Lord himself will give you a sign: the virgin will be with child and will give birth to a son, and will call him Immanuel [which means God with us] (Isaiah 7:14).

This prophecy given to Isaiah is quoted in Matthew 1:22-23 as a fulfilment of Isaiah 7:14.

> For unto us a child is born, to us a son is given, and the government will be on his shoulders.  And he will be called Wonderful Counsellor, Mighty God, Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace (Isaiah 9:6).

The Old Testament prophets acted in faith based on God’s promises.  Many of them are listed in Hebrews chapter 11.  They were all living by faith when they died, confident in God’s promises:

> These were all commended for their faith, yet none of them received what had been promised (Hebrews 11:39).

[This article](https://www.gotquestions.org/Old-Testament-Christ.html) gives a useful summary of Old Testament prophesies about the future Messiah.